# Rails two processes unable to see each others db updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

If we send two requests in parallel, the db updates of one process are not visible to other process. Actually we are uploading files with some data and there is unique check (not on model or db level, controlled by some business rules) on a particular attribute.

```
Process 1:
foo1 = Foo.new(data from file)
foo1.number = 1 # from file
foo1.save
foo1.process # it will only get processed if there is no other Foo with same number i.e. 1

Process 2:
foo2 = Foo.new(data from file)
foo2.number = 1 # some other user has uploaded the file with same number
foo2.save
foo2.process # it will only get processed if there is no other Foo with same number i.e. 1
```

How can I handle this situation so that I can let one process complete and make the Foo.number (db query) available to other process? I am not using database transaction.

`Rails 3.2.9`, `Apache`,`Phusion_Passenger 4`

## Edit

Please note that `foo1` and `foo2` are different records in database, and what I want is to be able process1 see foo2.number of process2 and vice versa so that I can make one of them as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should use [Optimistic Lock](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) ([here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) is more details). In this case only one request will have ability to modify data.

Comment: thanks @ethyl, please note that `foo1` and `foo2` are different records in database, and what I want is to be able `process1` see `foo2.number` of `process2` and vice versa so that I can make one of them as duplicate. (edited the question above)